# How to select polygons by distance to a single polygon in another layer?

Tags: qgis, distance, select-by-location

I have a shapefile A with a group of polygons, lakes.
Now I want to select the polygons(lakes) that are within a specific distance to a polygon in a second shapefile, B, with the polygon a city.

In other words, I am looking for something like ArcGIS "Select By Location" and "are within a distance of the source layer feature"

I tried Select by Location, and also Select by Radius, but didn't manage to get any of them to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to first buffer your city polygon and then use the **Spatial query** plugin with *intersect*.

Adding a "within a distance of" option would be a nice extra for the Spatial query plugin.

Comment: A strong +1 to your comment about adding the "Within distance of" option to the spatial query plugin.  That seems like a basic facet that GIS software needs to be able to handle without first creating a buffer layer of your features.